# my update method in Dbset does not working and it just add another row in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to learn web development with asp.net 6 and I'm trying to update a category that I created .I've written a get and a post method but it just doesn't working in Edit action and it is adding a new row in database instead of updating.

this is my edit action in category controller

```
        //GET
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if(id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var CategoryFromDb = _db.Categories.Find(id);
            if (CategoryFromDb == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(CategoryFromDb);
        }

        //POST
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(Category obj)
        {
            if (obj.Name == obj.DisplayOrder.ToString())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("name", "The DisplayOrder cannot exactly match the Name.");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Categories.Update(obj);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Category");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
    }
```

this is my Edit.cshtml

```
@model Category

<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Edit Category</h2>
            <hr/>
            <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3" style="  width: 500px;clear: both;">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input style="width: 100%;clear: both;" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-bg-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3" style="  width: 500px;clear: both;">
            <label asp-for="DisplayOrder"></label>
            <input style="width: 100%;clear: both;" asp-for="DisplayOrder" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DisplayOrder" class="text-bg-danger"></span>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px;">Update</button>
        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my category model

```
 public class Category
    {

        [Key]
        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Display Order")]
        [Range (1,100,ErrorMessage ="Not in Range of Display Order")]
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

and this is my index view part that I created Edit button

```
                    <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                            <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id ="@obj.CategoryID" ><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>Edit</a>
                    </div>
```

and it's adding a new row to database instead of updating the database based on the primary key
please help me...
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you're not filling in the model correctly - namely, your View doesn't fill in the CategoryID, so the controller doesn't "know" which Category to update. You need to modify your View similar to this (I've added the line right below `<form>`):

```
@model Category

<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryID)
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Edit Category</h2>
            <hr/>
            <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3" style="  width: 500px;clear: both;">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input style="width: 100%;clear: both;" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-bg-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3" style="  width: 500px;clear: both;">
            <label asp-for="DisplayOrder"></label>
            <input style="width: 100%;clear: both;" asp-for="DisplayOrder" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DisplayOrder" class="text-bg-danger"></span>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px;">Update</button>
        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</form>
```